# Control where a new field is stored in the database D7

Tags: entities, nodes

I am interested in adding a field to the 'Product' content type in Ubercart 3 / Drupal 7.  I have read up on topics like [field_create_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) and `db_add_field()` but I want my field to be stored as an additional column in the `uc_products` table in my database.  In addition, I want my new field (qid) to be called whenever I call up the `$node` value.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Altering a column in a table created by core or contrib is not a good idea unless you are very sure of what you are doing. For what purpose do you want this custom column?

Comment: It's a quote field with a lot of important information about each individual product.  I feel as though I have seen other contributed modules do this in the past.

Comment: Why is its place in the database important to you?

Comment: Thats a good question.  It's more of a housekeeping issue.  I guess I should be relying on the node api to sort through my fields and load / store my added field of qid, eh?  Edit: I guess if I don't like using the node / field system I shouldn't be using Drupal in the first place :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer done in D7.
You will want to use a proper field (which is stored in its own table and has many benefits over a simple column).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have implemented and I now see the benefits of the field system.